# Get all the orders that were purchased along with group of certain items in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to know how will I be able to Get all the orders that were purchased along with group of certain items. I have a master items table where it contains around 90 Based Items and I have My order table that contains all the receipts. so the output show shows all the orders that were purchased along with my based items in my Item Table.

## Master Item Table:

```
ItemCode
-------
10001        
10002        
10003        
10004
```

## Order Table:

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemCode  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             16       10002    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       2             7        10044    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

4        06/08/2018     Donuts        7             17       10066    122-7

1        06/08/2018     Bread         1             7        10003    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3

3        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       7             17       10044    122-5

4        06/08/2018     Ice Coffee    7             17       10050    122-6
```

## Result:

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemCode  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             16       10002    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Ice Tea       2             7        10044    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

1        06/08/2018     Bread         1             7        10003    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
```

the query output has to return to me all the transaction that are purchased along with my Item master table values only, for example the output query didn't return the Order No: 122-6 as the Item Code not present in my master item code while Order No:122-1 is shown because one or two of my ItemCode are present in the order & Master Item table

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I have update the desired output.

Comment: The output looks the same as the input but in a different order. Is this all you need help with, how to sort?

Comment: Why did your expect result contain `ItemCode=10044`, because there isn't `ItemCode=10044` in `Master` table.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no, the sorting doesn't matter to me here, the query output has to return to me all the transaction that are purchased along with my Item master table values only, for example the output query didn't rerun the Order No: 122-6 as the Item Code not present in my master item code.

Comment: @D-Shih he query output has to return to me all the transaction that are purchased along with my Item master table values only, for example the output query didn't return the Order No: 122-6 as the Item Code not present in my master item code while Order No:122-1 is shown because one or two of my ItemCode are present in the order & Master Item table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to write a subquery, which `OrderNo` and `SiteID` is matched.

then do `join` to `[Order]` table to get your expect result.

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM [Order] o JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo,SiteID
    FROM MasterItem m 
    JOIN [Order] o on o.ItemCode = m.ItemCode
) t1 on t1.OrderNo = o.OrderNo and t1.SiteID = o.SiteID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=588d37cb3a17c9ad0e62648a5b3c117a)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (substitute your own table names)

```
select * from [Order]
where [OrderNo] in (
    select distinct [OrderNo] 
    from [Order] o
    inner join [MasterItem] m on o.[ItemCode] = m.[ItemCode]
)
```

The subquery gets a list of orders that have the desired items in it, then this is used to select all rows from the Orders table.  In other words, this will return all `Order` rows (any item) where there is an item in the order that is in the list of items in the `MasterItem` table.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join

```
SELECT * FROM Order o
JOIN Item i ON i.itemCode = o.itemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join:

```
select * from ordertable o
inner join mastertable m on o.itemcode=m.itemcode
```

Answer (score 0):

I wold use exists

```
select * from [Order] o
where exists(select 1 from
(SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo,SiteID
    FROM MasterItem m 
    JOIN [Order] o on o.ItemCode = m.ItemCode
    ) t
    where t.OrderNo=o.OrderNo and t.SiteID=o.SiteID
    )
```

Comment: exists need to use a dependent subquery, otherwise, it returns the same value for each row of the outer query. Therefore, your solution is not correct.

Comment: It is still not correct. See the upvoted solutions. They join according to the `OrderNo`. There is a reason for that. It comes from the OP request (see his response to D-shih).